# How to get confirmation before displaying the popup editor window for Kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When user click on edit command, I would like to display popup editor window only after user confirmation. Actually, I am displaying a report in a editor and i would like to get confirmation from user before displaying this report.

I already tried events.Edit("onGridEdit") and then in onGridEdit(e) javascript function tried as below:

```
if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to buy this report ')) {
        e.preventDefault();            
    }
```

but it is not working. It display the confirmation dialogue but opens the editor window as well.

Any suggestion?

Comment: first, you aren't providing enough code sample here.. secondly, `e.preventDefault` is used to keep an event from bubbling. it does not stop execution of a script or wait for some asychronous event to complete. Additionally, `confirm` invokes a prompt and gives it focus.. I think you provide it a callback function. Lastly, if you're defining a new mechanism you should make that into a custom command.

Comment: hmm.. upon further review.. prompts, alerts, and windows are quite different then telerik's Ajax rad control versions. I've seen one implementation of `bind("close", CallBackFn)` on the window.. it's viable, but I would like to review and/or produce a better solution.  you can see his implementation here: http://www.code-sample.com/2014/06/kendo-ui-confirmation-dialog.html .. .additionally, here is the demo sample on custom commands (which popups up a kendo window) http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/custom-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to meet you halfway on this answer for the moment.

The following sample uses a **custom command** and **closures** (variables and nested functions) that are binded to the button click events within the window.wrapper.

```js
var sharedDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
    {
        pageSize: 20,
        data: [
            {"id": 0, "first" : "George", "last" : "Washingon", "ATK" : 9000, "DEF" : 500},
            {"id": 1, "first" : "John", "last" : "Adams", "ATK" : 50, "DEF" : 5000},
            {"id": 2, "first" : "Thomas", "last" : "Jefferson",  "ATK" : 100, "DEF" : 5000}
        ],
        autoSync: true,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "id",
                fields: {
                    id: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                    first: { validation: { required: true } },
                    last: { validation: { required: true } },
                    ATK: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1}},
                    DEF: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1}}
                }
            }
        }
    });
    
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: sharedDataSource,
    pageable: true,
    height: 550,
    editable: "inline",
    columns: [
        { field: "first", title: "First"},
        { field: "last", title: "Last"},
        { field: "ATK", title: "Attack"},
        { field: "DEF", title: "Defense"},
        { command: { text: "View Details", click: showDetails }, title: " ", width: "180px" }
    ]
});


var wnd = $("#details").kendoWindow({
    title: "Customer Details",
    modal: true,
    visible: false,
    resizable: false,
    width: 300
}).data("kendoWindow");


var detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#template").html());




function showDetails(eArg) {  
    console.clear();
    eArg.preventDefault();
    
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(eArg.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    console.log(dataItem);
    dataItem._self = JSON.stringify(dataItem);
    wnd.content(detailsTemplate(dataItem));
    wnd.wrapper.find("button.btn-confirm").click(confirmed.bind(null, wnd));
    wnd.wrapper.find("button.btn-cancel").click(cancel.bind(null, wnd));
    wnd.center().open();
    
   function confirmed(e)
   {
       console.log("Confirmed");
       wnd.close();       
       console.log(eArg);
       console.log(e);
       console.log(grid);
       console.log(dataItem.parent());
       dataItem._events.change[0](dataItem);
   }

   function cancel(e)
   {
       console.log("Cancel");
       wnd.close();
   }
}
```

```css
#details-container
                {
                    padding: 10px;
    background-color:blue;
                }

                #details-container h2
                {
                    margin: 0;
                }

                #details-container
                {
                    color: #8c8c8c;
                }

                #details-container dt
                {
                    margin:0;
                    display: inline;
                }
.k-i-close {background-color:white;content: 'X'};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="Stylesheet" />

<div id="grid"></div>
<div id="details"></div>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">    
    <div id="details-container">
        <h2>#= first # #= last #</h2>
        <dl>
            <dt>Attack: #= ATK #</dt>
            <dt>Defense: #= DEF #</dt>
        </dl>
        <button class="btn-confirm">Confirm</button>
        <button class="btn-cancel">Confirm</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mzq4sxot/

Comment: in the nested functions, you can see I can access the dataItem, window, grid.. and both the commend and window event. At the moment, I'm not sure how to invoke the edit command programmatically..